# Run a subroutine (label) in a separate window using batch?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I can call a label in the same batch using

```
CALL :LABEL
```

but I can t find a way to run it in a separate window, nothing of this works:

```
start "" :LABEL

cmd /c :LABEL 

start "" call :LABEL
```

The only way I found is calling a separate batch file, but this is not a solution because I want to have all the code in the same batch for ease of use and access. Do you know any posible solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Windows batch doesn't support this, your solution may be an `if` at the very beginning of your batch file, checking for a specific first argument:

```
if "%~1"=="gotolabel" goto %~2
```

With this, you may insert calls to labels like this (`%~dpnx0` evaluates to the path+name of your batch, `%COMSPEC%` evaluates to cmd.exe):

```
start "" "%COMSPEC%" /c "%~dpnx0" "gotolabel" LABEL
```

...or, without a new window:

```
"%COMSPEC%" /c "%~dpnx0" "gotolabel" LABEL
```